# WHy can't I  select the MySQL database from PHP? I get "access denied"

Tags: php, mysql, database

I connected to MySQL from PHP using root user. Connection object was `$con`. The connection was successful.

I wanted to select a particular database so I used `mysql_select_db('database', $con)`, but I got an `'Access denied for user '@'localhost' to database'` error.

I can't understand why I got an access denied error, as I am using root user. I double-checked the grants for root and it has all privileges on *.*. And I am able to execute queries on this particular database through the command line client using root. I am running everything on my local machine.

Comment: This has no bearing on your specific problem, but PLEASE STOP USING mysql_* functions in PHP. Learn PDO. That is all.

Comment: what's wrong with using mysql_* functions? what about mysqli_?

Comment: @Frank http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the root account (which is a BAD idea regardless of what you're trying to do). The error message clearly states `... for user ''@localhost`: there's no username in there, so you've connected with no username at all.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your `mysql_connect(host, username, password)` you have entered the wrong details.

You usually need a password, for secure hosting. This can be acquired from you hosting provider, and the username is also defined from your hosting provider or by you. The host in usually localhost.

You must add this `mysql_connect` to each of the pages you are using php functions with a mysql database.